# Insert into first row when the table has a primary key set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I spent all day creating then manually inserting into some tables I created today that look like this:

```
  ID - Int (Primary Key set to Auto Increment)

  Value - Varchar
```

But then I realized I had forgotten to insert a value of "--" into the first row of each table.

Is it possible to maybe add 1 to the ID no for each of the values currently in the table then insert the "--" value into the first row?

Comment: Why would you want to insert `--` into a numeric column.  Also, what database are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: is it possible, yes (the varchar column)

Comment: killed `mysql` tag due to tsql. Tweak accordingly.

Comment: Just update your table for the ID of 1, like this: `Update yourTable set Value = '--' where id = 1` You may need to re-insert the value that was with ID of 1

Comment: maybe his prev ordering mattered @cha. Plus you stomped on a value he forgot. Just having fun :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to fix it is to update the record with the ID=1 to '--':

```
update yourTable set Value = '--' where id = 1
```

Then you will be required to re-insert the first record into the table:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (Value) 
VALUES('the value that was originally inserted as 1')
```

However, if the order of the already inserted records is important then you can insert the '--' value as the ID = 0. In this case you need to disable the IDENTITY column using the [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourTable ON

INSERT INTO yourTable (ID, Value) 
VALUES(0, '--')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourTable OFF
```

This way the order of inserted records will be preserved and the '--' will be inserted with the ID of 0

BTW, for mySQL you can insert into the IDENTITY column by default

Answer (score 0):

Because Your `ID column` auto increment (`IDENTITY`), when you `insert`, you mustn't `insert` `ID column`. To `insert` your table, you just `insert` other columns.
Code `insert` like this:

```
INSERT INTO Your_Table (ColA, ColB, ...)  -- `except identity colums`
VALUES (A, B, ...)

INSERT INTO Your_Table
VALUES (A, B, ...) -- except identity colums

INSERT INTO Your_Table
SELECT ColA, ColB, ... FROM Other_Table -- except identity colums
```

If Your_Table empty:

```
INSERT INTO Your_Table (Value)
VALUES ('--')

INSERT INTO Your_Table
SELECT '--'
```

If not:

```
 UPDATE Your_Table
 SET Value = '--'
 WHERE ID = 1


------------------------ More Infor -------------------------------------------
```

If you want to first row have ID = 1. You can set ID column have IDENTITY(1,1). Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Your_Table
(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Value VARCHAR(50) NULL
)
```

Or, After you create `Your_Table`, you can set **right-click** `Your_Table`, select **Design**, select `ID column`. Look **Column Properties** below, expand **Identity Specification**, Double click **(Is identity)**, then set value `Identity Increment` and `Identity Seed`